# Moodle errors with Debian Warning: mkdir()

Tags: chmod, moodle

Right now I have Debian running Moodle 2.3 and when I imported the database over I get these errors when connecting to the Moodle homepage.

http://pastebin.com/NKEWXZdp

What am I doing wrong? I set the permissions to 0777 for a temporary fix but that doesn't work.

My directory goes /var/www/edu

I gave www and edu 0777 but I still get errors?

Answer (score 0):

As the provided error list suggests, Moodle is looking for the moodledata directory and contents in /var/moodledata/ . I know that this folder normally goes one level above the public web directory ( /var/www/edu/ ) so in this case, you should check whether your moodledata directory is actually held here: /var/www/moodledata/ .

If so, you should update /var/www/edu/configuration.php to provide the correct moodledata directory details. In any case, you should check that the details held in /var/www/edu/configuration.php marry up with the actual location of moodledata and that moodledata and all of its subdirectories have appropriate permissions (you can test this by changing to 777 and then copy over the originals if this does work and find which specific permissions need to change).

Good luck!